# Configuring conditional compilation symbol in app.config file

Tags: .net, app-config, compilation

Can we configure conditional compilation symbol in app.config file? If it is possible then let us know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

They are done at different times - one at compile time one at run time. If you are compiling code at run time (e.g. dynamic creation of code) then you could use a simple [appSetting](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx). Finally there is an option where you add a entry in the VBPROJ/CSPROJ/MSBUILD file to parse the config file and add an appropriate symbol using the CreateProperty task.